# 4D input tensor for tensorflow RNN

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

Using tensorflow for NLP tasks, I am usually passing a 3D tensor as input, with rank 3, such as [batch_size,time_steps,embedding_dimension]

The code for the RNN looks like this:

```
lstm_cell =tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(n_hidden)
lstm_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(lstm_cell, output_keep_prob=dropout)
outputs, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell=lstm_cell, inputs=x,sequence_length=seq_len, dtype=tf.float32,time_major=False)   ## outputs is a list of matrices
```

seq_len is of shape [batch_size], and the outputs is a tensor of shape (batch_size,rnn_dimension). This works fine.

Is it possible to input a 4D tensor of shape: [batch_size,time_steps,num_features,embedding_dimension] and also providing a rank2 sequence_length of shape [batch_size,num_features] ?

As an output I would expect a tensor of shape : [num_features,batch_size,rnn_dimension]

Is anyone using input tensor with rank higher than 3? How would you adapt the code, just using the 4 rank tensor directly fails.

```
Dimension must be 4 but is 3 for 'test_scope/transpose' (op: 'Transpose') with input shapes: [?,156,12,300], [3].

Dimension must be 4 but is 3 for 'test_scope_1/transpose' (op: 'Transpose') with input shapes: [?,12,156,300], [3].
```

Comment: Looks like your error is not from your RNN but a Transpose operation where you let a rank 3 shape as permutation instead of a rank 4.